# Setting local development with Docker and dockerizing repositories?

Tags: docker, localhost, development-environment

I have quite recently started learning Docker and what I'd like to do is to dockerize all my existing projects and all new ones. So basically set my local dev environment on Docker, but keep each project/repository isolated if that makes sence, as one php-app might be on php5 and another one on php7 etc.

What I usually did before was to place all my projects/repositories under `home/Repositories` folder, so I want to follow the same pattern, although each project folder will run on each own environment.

I have already installed Docker on my OS (I'm on Ubuntu Linux completely fresh installation, so no PHP or anything else is installed), however I'd like to ask a few questions as I don't have any previous experience with Docker

As far as I understand each project/repository should contain a `docker-compose.yml` file on the root directory and a `docker` folder where I put all the `Dockerfiles`, is that right?

```
- home
-- Repositories
--- a-laravel-project
---- docker // folder that has all required containers, like PHP, Mysql, Nginx conf etc etc
---- docker-compose.yml
---- index.php

--- another-oop-php-project
---- docker // folder that has all required containers, like PHP, Mysql, etc etc
---- docker-compose.yml
---- index.php
```

Do I also need to have install natively Git? I guess in order to dockerize all my existing repositories I need to clone them first so in this case git is (pre)required, correct?

Thanks in advance, any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your repositories directory for sure. You don't need any special layout for Docker at all.

Lets say that in your pre-docker view of the world your environment was:

- repositories

  - project1

    - index.php
  - project2

    - index.php

You then add a Dockerfile (and if you want docker-compose.yml) to each project:

- repositories

  - project1

    - index.php
    - Dockerfile
  - project2

    - index.php
    - Dockerfile

You mention a "folder that has all required containers". That's not quite right. All your docker containers will be in Docker's own directory structure (that you do not want to mess with manually). What you do need to be concerned with is how to build your dependencies into your docker container for each project.

Lets say your project1 will use just php, so you could make use of the official php docker container (https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

Then your Dockerfile could be something like

```
FROM php:7.0-cli
COPY index.php /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

Or if you wanted to build your own from ubuntu or something. You start with the base ubuntu image and then install the dependencies you need on that ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install php # Or whatever is appropriate, I don't use php
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

Then when you're in `project1` directory and want to build your docker container. Then run it.

```
docker build -t project1:latest .
docker run project1:latest
```

Note on source files:

It's pretty common to want to keep your source files outside of your docker container, but run your test server inside the docker container. In that case you'll want to do something like:

```
docker run \
  -v /home/repositories/project1:/project1 \
  php:7.0-cli \
  php /project1/index.php
```

That bind mounts your source code directory from your machine into a container in which you run the php server. Also don't forget if you're running a development server inside the docker container you'll need to bind ports so you can connect to a port on your localhost and it be forwarded to the container.

There is lots of good information you might be interested to read on https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ if you're using php.

Git, I would still have installed on your host especially if mounting your source code into the container as I described

Comment: About the `docker` folder I said for having all containers, what I was trying to say before is that this folder will basically have all `Dockerfiles` if that makes sence. In regards to Git, so I need to have a native installation on my OS (Ubuntu), correct?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, then your structure makes sense if you need to build multiple Docker containers for a single project. Say if you needed to build a custom nginx as well as a custom php then you'd have docker/php/Dockerfile and docker/nginx/Dockerfile. That would be neat. Personally I prefer to try and minimize how many custom docker containers I need to build in favour of trying to use standard ones. E.g. using stock nginx image and configuring it with environment variables and command arguments when run (or using equivalent docker compose).

Comment: Yes, native git on your ubuntu. I always manage my source, outside of the Docker container.

Comment: Is it better to use generators like phpdocker.io or laradoc instead to get something up and running quickly?

Comment: I think that's very much personal preference. Personally I like to understand how to do these things manually before I let a tool do it for me, otherwise when things go wrong I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: how can I use composer on my php apps (eg laravel app) without having it globally/nativelly installed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How could you use `docker-compose` without having it installed? It's even built-in to modern versions of Docker.

Comment: Not docker-compose, the composer (https://getcomposer.org/) the tool that pulls all php packages in a app, like in laravel

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I'd ask a new question as it's not related to this one really.